# How to do a grep in a ascii with confidence 1.0 file

Tags: powershell, shell

I'm using windows 10. I 'm encountering something odd. I can not get any output from my grep command in a list of log files.

For testing, I used these kind of command on the word which contains all the files :

```
Select-String -Path *.log -Pattern OPENED
findstr /i "OPENED" *.log
grep -r "OPENED" *.log
```

I've not any output.

I installed chardetect python script that gave the version of charactère of the log files :

```
chardetect file.log
file.log: ascii with confidence 1.0
```

How to do a grep in these kind of files ?

Comment: your top select-string works fine for me, if the directory the prompt is in contains .log files. are you on the correct path? do you have permissions to the files? Note that this command will NOT recurse into subdirectories, so all the files must be in the current dir.

Comment: @FrankThomas I checked the properties of the directory and some files. it's good. I launched the select-string in the good directory. As well, I did a Select-string on a specific file, I've got nothing.   I can open the log file with Notepad++. The word OPENED it's present in each files.

Answer (score 0):

I post my solution, it might help.

Here this page help me to find the good option of `Select-String` command :

https://ss64.com/ps/select-string.html

I used the `-Encoding` option like this :

```
Select-String -Path *.log -Pattern OPENED -Encoding unicode
```

I got something I search :

```
ID_647318.log:1:LOG FILE OPENED
ID_647318.log:12:LOG FILE OPENED
ID_645559.log:1:LOG FILE OPENED
ID_645559.log:12:LOG FILE OPENED
ID_645562.log:1:LOG FILE OPENED
ID_645562.log:12:LOG FILE OPENED
```